# Line's covered shown in WebStorm sidebar

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I can't figure out how to make this information disappear. In the sidebar, where directory structure is shown, near each file, I see "lines covered". It's really annoying when I don't know how I added this. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-between-code-coverage-suites.html -- opt+command+F6 and select No Coverage

Answer (score 0):

You must have run either your [tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/code-coverage.html#ws_coverage_run) or [application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/capturing-unused-javascript-code.html) in the coverage mode.

You won't see the coverage results after re-opening the project